# Read substring between two strings/characters

Tags: regex, perl

How do I only extract strings between two characters/strings?

For example, in this input:

```
16  Xe7-0-0-0 (84.16.14.162)  195.537 ms  195.532 ms 84.16.10.2 (84.16.10.2)  131.802 ms
```

I want to get all the millisecond times specifically.
It is between a `' '` whitespace and `" ms"` string.

So, with that input, I should be able to get an output like this:

```
195.537 195.532 131.802
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @times = $str =~ / (\S+) ms/g;
```

Comment: @Evan: `\S+` matches one or more *non-space* characters. `$str` is your input line

Comment: Yeah, I got it, the $str is the incoming string.  Thanks